# Download Siri as SAPI voice?

Tags: windows, text-to-speech, sapi, siri

Is it possible to get Siri's voice as a SAPI package to install? German would be the best choice! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

No.  Siri is an Apple product, and they have no interest in supporting Microsoft or In diluting their brand by having their signature voice appear in other products.